# Sbt project imports: error and warnings

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Each time I add dependencies in my build.sbt and then refresh Intellij to import the dependency it throws me such a warning-error:

```
    [warn] [FAILED ] org.scalatools.time#time_2.8.0;0.5!time_2.8.0.jar(src): (0ms) 
    [warn] ==== local: tried 
    [warn] /home/xxx/.ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.time/time_2.8.0/0.5/srcs/time_2.8.0-sources.jar 
    [warn] ==== public: tried  
    [warn] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/time/time_2.8.0/0.5/time_2.8.0-0.5-sources.jar 
    [warn] [FAILED ] org.scala-tools.time#time_2.8.0;0.5!time_2.8.0.jar(doc): (0ms) 
    [warn] ==== local: tried 
    [warn] /home/xxx/.ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.time/time_2.8.0/0.5/docs/time_2.8.0-javadoc.jar 
    [warn] ==== public: tried 
    [warn] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/time/time_2.8.0/0.5/time_2.8.0-0.5-javadoc.jar 
    [warn]:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
    [warn] :: FAILED DOWNLOADS :: 
    [warn] :: ^ see resolution messages for details ^ :: 
    [warn] :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 
    [warn] :: org.scala-tools.time#time_2.8.0;0.5!time_2.8.0.jar(src) 
    [warn] :: org.scala-tools.time#time_2.8.0;0.5!time_2.8.0.jar(doc)
    [warn]
```

It turns out that the dependency which I add,here it is:

```
    libraryDependencies += "org.scala-tools.time" % "time_2.8.0" % "0.5"
```

works perfectly find and I can use all methods (at least as it looks to be..)
But I don't understand why intellij throws always such an error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of scala are you using?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ is trying to fetch the Scaladoc/Javadoc and sources jars for your time dependency (see the `(src)` and `(doc)` suffix) for your convenience, but it's not a fatal error.

Comment: But at the end the time dependency was successfully added to my external libraries, although I was getting this error... I was thinking that if intellij fails to import the src jars then I won't be able to use all methods provided by this dependency, instead everything works fine.

Comment: You can use all the methods because you have the binary, compiled jar. IntelliJ can see and bind to the methods in that.